# How to get the threshold value of k-means algorithm that is used to binarize the images?

Tags: matlab, k-means

I applied k-means algorithm for segmenting images. I used built in k-means function. It works properly but I want to know the threshold value that converts it to binary images in k-means method. For example, we can get threshold value by using built in function in MATLAB:

```
threshold=graythresh(grayscaledImage);
a=im2bw(a,threshold);
%Applying k-means....
imdata=reshape(grayscaledImage,[],1);
imdata=double(imdata);
[imdx mn]=kmeans(imdata,2);
imIdx=reshape(imdx,size(grayscaledImage));
imshow(imIdx,[]);
```

Comment: What makes you think that the values are binarized before applying k-means?

Comment: No, I didnot binarize before applying k-means.I used k-means parts separately.

Comment: There is no binarization in k-means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, k-means and the well known Otsu threshold for binarizing intensity images based on a global threshold have an interesting relationship:

http://www-cs.engr.ccny.cuny.edu/~wolberg/cs470/doc/Otsu-KMeansHIS09.pdf

It can be shown that k-means is a locally optimal, iterative solution to the same objective function as Otsu, where Otsu is a globally optimal, non-iterative solution.

Given greyscale intensity data, one could compute a threshold based on otsu, which can be expressed in MATLAB using [graythresh](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html), or [otsuthresh](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/otsuthresh.html), depending on which interface you prefer.

```
A = imread('cameraman.tif');
A = im2double(A);
totsu = otsuthresh(histcounts(A,10000))
[~,c] = kmeans(A(:),2,'Replicates',10);
tkmeans = mean(c)
```

You can obtain a grayscale threshold from kmeans by just finding the midpoint of the two centroids, which should make sense geometrically since on either side of that midpoint, you are closer to one of the centroids or the other, and should therefore lie in that respective cluster.

```
totsu =

    0.3308


tkmeans =

    0.3472
```

Comment: Thanks.Actually i wanted this type of answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can't get the threshold because there is no threshold in the kmeans algorithm.

K-means is a clustering algorithm, it returns clusters which in many cases cannot be obtained with a simple thresholding.

See [this link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) to learn further on how k-means works.

Comment: When k = 2, with intensity image information, you can obtain a threshold by taking the mean of the two cluster centroid locations returned by kmeans.

Comment: @Alex Right! Nice answer.